# How to exctract zip multipart to List<Files> and then make multiparts of each file?

Tags: java, zip, multipart

This is my service  but it's doesn't work , all mockmultiparts has same size and wrong md-5 hash.

```
public void zipExt(MultipartFile zipFile, long documentId) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Document document = documentRepository.getDocumentById(documentId);
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream());
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
      
        while (zipEntry != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while ((i = zipInputStream.read(data)) != - 1) { byteArrayOutputStream.write(data, 0, i); }
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
//            file to multipartFile
            String name = zipEntry.getName();
            String originalFileName = zipEntry.getName();
            String contentType = "text/plain";
            MultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(name,
                    originalFileName, contentType, data);
            statAnalysisService.doAnalysis(mockMultipartFile,fileToSave);//save to analyzes
            zipArchiveList.add(zipEntry.getName());
            zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();

        }
        return zipArchiveList;
    }
```

please help .i need multipart for analysis it

Comment: You are passing `data`, which is a 1024-byte buffer, to your MockMultipartFile creation.  Perhaps you meant to pass `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`?  Or did you intend every multipart to be exactly 1024 bytes long, regardless of the size of the corresponding zip entry?  (Caution: Reading the entire entry into a ByteArrayOutputStream will cause performance problems for large zip entries.)

Comment: Thanks , your byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() really help me !!!!